# I am not able to deliver my image under the h2 due to some technical error

Tags: html, css

I am not able to run my code and produce an image under header 2

Are there any reason why as I have already input the right code.

I believe another css layout is blocking the image from popping out. Below here is the code to check

```
<div class="login-box">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="" required="">
            <label>Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="password" name="" required="">
            <label>Password</label>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            Submit
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="section-container">
        <h2 class="title-container">Here are my other socials you can find me on
        </h2>

        <img src="//placekitten.com/150/150" alt="">Image 

      </div>
```

My CSS below

```
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  }
  
  .login-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 78%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .login-box h2 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .login-box .user-box label {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
  .login-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  .login-box form a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px
  }
  
  .login-box a:hover {
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 25px #03e9f4,
                0 0 50px #03e9f4,
                0 0 100px #03e9f4;
  }
  
  .login-box a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim1 {
    0% {
      left: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      left: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .25s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim2 {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      top: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .5s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim3 {
    0% {
      right: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      right: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .75s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim4 {
    0% {
      bottom: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      bottom: 100%;
    }
  }
  
.section-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 60deg, rgba(57, 60, 90, 0.85), rgba(180, 180, 120, 0.5) );
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: rgb(56, 50, 50) 1px 1px
}

.title-container {

    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-top: 1px black solid;


}
```

I tried to put the img code under . but did not get the image to pop up under the h2 tag

Comment: Adding an alt text would be useful too, in case their is an issue with the link.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  }
  
  .login-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 78%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .login-box h2 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .login-box .user-box label {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  .login-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
  .login-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  .login-box form a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px
  }
  
  .login-box a:hover {
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 25px #03e9f4,
                0 0 50px #03e9f4,
                0 0 100px #03e9f4;
  }
  
  .login-box a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim1 {
    0% {
      left: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      left: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .25s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim2 {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      top: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .5s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim3 {
    0% {
      right: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      right: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .login-box a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .75s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim4 {
    0% {
      bottom: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      bottom: 100%;
    }
  }
  
.section-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 60deg, rgba(57, 60, 90, 0.85), rgba(180, 180, 120, 0.5) );
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: rgb(56, 50, 50) 1px 1px
}

.title-container {

    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-top: 1px black solid;


}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="" required="">
            <label>Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="password" name="" required="">
            <label>Password</label>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            Submit
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="section-container">
        <h2 class="title-container">Here are my other socials you can find me on
        </h2>

        <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="">Image 

      </div>
```

Not a css issue. You don't have the correct path to the image. I've inserted the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

The margin on the heading element is causing this.
Instead of adding the `img` element, consider adding the image as a background to another element...

CSS added:

```css
body {
  background: url("//placekitten.com/150/150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Below I have added it to the `body`, but this could be done to any element of your choosing really.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
}

.login-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.login-box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-box .user-box {
  position: relative;
}

.login-box .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.login-box .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.login-box .user-box input:focus~label,
.login-box .user-box input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-box form a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

.login-box a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4, 0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.login-box a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

.section-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 60deg, rgba(57, 60, 90, 0.85), rgba(180, 180, 120, 0.5));
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: rgb(56, 50, 50) 1px 1px
}

.title-container {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
}

body {
  background: url("//placekitten.com/150/150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input type="password" name="" required="">
      <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span> Submit
    </a>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="section-container">
  <h2 class="title-container">Here are my other socials you can find me on
  </h2>

</div>
```